# Not able to Login this website https://www.bestpricewholesale.co.in/Registration/login.aspx in python scrapy project

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, twisted, scrapyd

Not able to Login only this website in python scrapy project. I want to scrap a login require website and i have already login many websites in my project but  not able to Login only this website in python scrapy project.I think i have problem in form response it's """Return the most likely field names for username and password""" but i am not sure and not able to solve this issue

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scraping.articles import ArticleItem
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log

class BestPriceGetCatUrl(InitSpider,BaseSpider):
    name = "BestPriceGetCatUrl"
    allowed_domains = ["bestpricewholesale.co.in"]
    login_page = 'https://www.bestpricewholesale.co.in/Registration/login.aspx'
    start_urls = ["http://www.bestpricewholesale.co.in/categories/Apparel--Home/cid-CK00002496.aspx"]

    def start_requests(self):
        return self.init_request()

    def init_request(self):
        return [Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)]

    def login(self, response):
        log.msg("hello i am here in login....")
        #args, url, method = fill_login_form(response.url, response.body, self.login_user, self.login_pass)
        #return FormRequest(url, method=method, formdata=args, callback=self.check_login_response)
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl01$Login1$UserName': 'username', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl01$Login1$Password': 'passward'}, callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        log.msg("in check login response : "+str(response))
        if "Logout" in response.body:
            for url in self.start_urls:
                nUrl = self.make_requests_from_url(url)
                yield Request("http://www.bestpricewholesale.co.in/categories/Apparel--Home/cid-CK00002496.aspx",callback=self.parseItems)
        else:
            self.log("Could not log in...")

    def parseItems(self, response):
        item = ArticleItem()
        item['title'] = "ranvijay"
        log.msg("***************    :   "+str(response.xpath("//*[@id='lblUserName']/label[@id='lblusrN']/text()").extract()))
        item['url'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='lblusrN']/text()").extract()
        item['name1'] = response.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl01_lblUserName']/text()").extract()
        yield item

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class ArticleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    url = Field()
    name1 = Field()
```

Comment: Make sure your username and password are correct. Make sure this works in Scrapy Shell before, and then proceed to coding.

Comment: yes i am sure i am giving right credential but sorry i can not share with you thanks

Comment: I am not asking you to share it. Did you try it in the Shell first? It is possible that what you see in the browser is not what Scrapy sees. Maybe there is not "Logout" in the response body after all, even when logged in.